# Jquery AutoComplete on Mutiple textboxes on ajax populated page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have two textboxes on a view having autocomplete functionality.I am using jQuery.UI.Autocomplete. These textboxes works fine when loaded as a page, When loaded in a view using ajax cal, its not working.

```
function PlanAutoComplete() {
       // debugger
        $("#txtPlanName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax (
                //some code here)
}    
                       });
    }

    function ProductAutoComplete() {
        // debugger
        $("#txtProductName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax(
//some code here
              );

        });
```

In document.ready i am calling as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#txtPlanName").bind("keydown.autocomplete", PlanAutoComplete);
            $("#txtProductName").bind("keydown.autocomplete", ProductAutoComplete);
            }
```

And Also .on function as below

```
 $('body').on('keydown.autocomplete', '#txtPlanName', PlanAutoComplete);
    $('body').on('keydown.autocomplete', '#txtProductName', ProductAutoComplete);
```

Here my first textbox named txtPlanName is working fine ,but the second text is not getting autopopulated.Where i am doing wrong.Please help .